# How to add new table in context ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Please, help me.
I had a file ImageContext:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace userGallery.Models
{
    public class ImageContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I create new model Slide and add string connect in ImageContext.
Result

```
...
public class ImageContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Slide> Slides { get; set; }
    }
...
```

How to update database to create a table Slides?

Screenshoot database table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cyMZ.png)

Comment: Looks like you have migrations enabled. Have you added a new one for the Slides table? add-migration CreateSlides, update-database

Comment: no result after your command

Comment: So you went to package manager console, entered those commands, they ran without error, but the database did not change? Is your connection string pointing at the database you are looking at?